# How to POST object with Restangular?

Tags: javascript, spring, angularjs, controller, restangular

I want to send object to Spring Controller with Angular JS and Restangular. That is how I try to do this:

```
var scoreTO = {
    score: parseFloat($scope.score.score),
    percentage: parseFloat($scope.score.percentage),
    date: (new Date()).getTime()
}
Restangular.one("scores").post(scoreTO);
```

There is transport object:

```
public class ScoreTO implements Serializable{
private double score;
private double percentage;
private long date;
public ScoreTO(){}
public ScoreTO(double score, double percentage, long date){
    this.score = score; this.percentage = percentage; this.date=date;
}

public double getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(double score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public double getPercentage() {
    return percentage;
}

public void setPercentage(double percentage) {
    this.percentage = percentage;
}

public long getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(long date) {
    this.date = date;
}

}
```

And there is how I try to catch request in Spring Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/score")
    public class ScoreController {

    (...)

    @RequestMapping(value="/scores", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String saveScore(@RequestBody ScoreTO scoreTO){
        scoreService.saveScore(scoreTO.getScore(), scoreTO.getPercentage(), 
                new Date(scoreTO.getDate()));
        return "";
    }
}
```

But if I try to send it, I got this error in browser console: 
`POST http://localhost:8084/wpisywarkaAngular/score/scores/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)` 
What am I doing wrong? I'll we very happy if anybody help me - thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to use `all` instead of `one`, another solution can be using `customPOST`...

```
Restangular.all("scores").post(scoreTO);
```